# Android SQLite error, NullPointerException is the bane of my existence

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I continually get the same `NPE` at run-time.

I'm trying to create a database with a table that gets its name from user input. I've got two classes, one that gets the information from the user and another that creates and handles the database.

1. ["Name Entry" activity code](http://pastebin.com/MKAqsK4G)
2. ["Database Handler" activity code](http://pastebin.com/nHstB4ff)
3. [logcat output](http://pastebin.com/aZh0nRXQ)

Comment: Boo hiss for not using conventional Java package naming.

Comment: I didn't use naming convention?  I had no idea...  What should i change

Comment: Package names are generally all lower-case. Not a big deal, but it can be a little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The String name is empty when you call name.toString() in your onCreate method in DbBasics .

```
static String name; // Null because you haven't assigned a string to it

DATABASE_TABLE = name.toString() + "Basics"; // Causes nullpointerException
```

Comment: Plus calling `toString()` on a string is superfluous.

Comment: AHA!!  Thank you!  Any suggestions on a way to get the name from the activity class?  I should add here that their are two ways that the database handler can be called.  In one case the name is known and in the other (the one in the pastebin link above) the name is given by the user.  the toString() is redundant, I'm editing it out now (I had it there for testing purposes before, it's not necessary now)

Comment: Why would the database name be given by the user? Just use the name that describes what the table is holding. It seems that it are users in your case. If the user provides something that you want to save, put it in the database. It's a really bad habit to do it like you, databases shouldn't be used like that.

Comment: use a public static global variable in another java class - you could set the string from your activity and read it from the database class

Comment: Well...I changed the name variable to a public static var in a different class, then made all the "name" references look at that variable instead.  Ran it, got a NPE :(    so that got me thinking, why don't I just try it with a string that I initialize...still NPE.  Here's a pastbin of the logcat data.  I'm never going to fix this...      http://pastebin.com/LvTzTzKy

Comment: Don't panic :) You WILL fix this, as it's a very basic problem: don't use an object that has not been initialised with a value before.

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement.  I'm still pretty new to java and coding in general; so this is just extremely disheartening.  I've been trying to fix this for almost a week now...  So I set the variable to something that's initialized and I'm still getting this illusive error.